# Why does nginx raise a 404 when it tries to acess static files on a FreeBSD server?

Tags: nginx, freebsd, static-files

I've got nginx 1.8.1 on a server running FreeBSD 10.2. I'm trying to serve files from a subdirectory of `/usr/local/www/` (which is default on FreeBSD), but for some reason, requests to the files I'm trying to access always result in a 404.

The file specifically is `/usr/local/www/example.com/pubic_html/index.html`, with `/usr/local/www` recursively owned by `www:www`, the user and group of the nginx worker process, with permissions recusrively set to `755`.

My `server` block, in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /usr/local/www/example.com/public_html;

    location /app {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

I'm honestly puzzled by this. I haven't had this issue on Linux with Nginx or Apache, and I haven't had this issue working with Apache on FreeBSD before, either. How can I get nginx to serve this static file?

**EDIT:** while requests for static files don't result in anything being logged to my `nginx-error.log`, it does result in normal 404 hit records in the `nginx-access.log`.

Comment: nginx error.log usually contains the answer.

Comment: There's nothing at all about these 404s in `nginx-error.log`. The entries in `nginx-access.log` aren't informative.

Comment: Did you try adding an `index index.html`? Also, unless you have a very good reason, `www-data` -being your webserver runtime user- should not have write permissions over the content it serves.

Comment: @SYN this is just a test; I'm trying to get familiar with setting up nginx on FreeBSD. Normally I would put it to 644 with ownership by `someuser:www-data`. (And just to nitpick; `www-data` is `www` on FreeBSD).

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: @MichaelHampton `mysite.com/index.html`

Comment: Hmm. You used someone else's domain name. Are you sure you're connecting to _your_ server and not _their_ server?

Comment: @MichaelHampton ... I'm sorry? I'm just putting `mysite.com` as a placeholder. I'm most certainly in control of this domain, I have the base URL forwarded to an app running on my server.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to use other people's domain names as examples, as it will confuse people. As for "the base URL forwarded to an app running on my server" .. what do you mean by that? There's nothing about that in your question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was under the impression that `mysite.com` is a fairly common placeholder and that it would be self-descriptive (and therefore obvious). I can update it to `example.com`, which is (IIRC) operated by IANA for this exact purpose. I didn't include details about the app because it's irrelevant to this question. I have a Golang web application running on port 8080 on the same machine, where requests on port 80 of a different `location` block inside the same `server` block are being forwarded to it.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's irrelevant? How so? Does your 404 page say "nginx" at the bottom, or does it simply say `404 page not found` in monospace text? It might be better if you posted the complete `server` block, just in case. BTW, `mysite.com` is a dodgy webhosting provider who really don't need any more free advertising.

Comment: The 404 page does include `nginx/1.8.1` at the bottom, yes. I'm quite sure that the remaining part of the `server` block is irrelevant, yes, but I'll post it all the same in a few minutes.

Comment: OK, I agree that's irrelevant. But it never hurts to make sure of everything. On that note: Are you absolutely 100% certain that you are typing `example.com/index.html` into your browser? Not `example.com` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

OK here's the thing: the default configurations for web servers in FreeBSD DO NOT use files inside the `sites-available` directory. Either you have to put the contents of the files inside `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or add this line to `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` so that it will read files inside the `sites-available` directory:

```
# virtual hosting
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
```

The same behavior also applies to Apache on FreeBSD. (Probably on other web servers as well, but I have experience only with these two.)

Comment: This line was in the default `nginx.conf` that was placed inside the initial `pkg install`. I've even intentionally missed semicolons in site config files to make sure it was really reading them; `nginx -s reload` errored (as expected) when this happened.

Comment: This was not like my case. Anyway you can put the content right inside nginx.conf instead to make sure that the configurations really work.

Comment: I _have_ made sure the configuration really works -- there's literally no need at this point to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other configuration files for Nginx?
I guess you have `listen <ip>` directive somewhere else so you should also use `listen <ip> default_server` or `listen <ip>:80 default_server` in your `example.com` configuration.

Comment: I have no other configuration files for nginx, and I'm confident this is the one being read; otherwise I wouldn't be able to do port forwarding on that web application at `/app`. I tried changing `default` to `default_server`, as well as explicitly writing the public IP of my server instead of just `80`, but no dice.

Comment: One more guess: have you tried `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` or remove `try_files` ? I've tried your config, and it works with `curl --resolve example.com:80:127.0.0.1 http://example.com/index.html` but failed with `curl --resolve example.com:80:127.0.0.1 http://example.com/` and `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` or removing `try_files` fixed this too.